# Approximating the integral $\int_1^x (t-[t])f'(t)dt$

Tags: asymptotics, analytic-number-theory

In applications of Euler's summation formula to find the asymptotic behaviour of something like $\sum_{n\leq x}f(n)$, one typically gets integrals of the form 
$$\int_1^x (t-[t])f'(t)dt$$
where $[t]$ denotes the integer part of $t$.

I've two questions, relating particularly to cases where the function $f(x)$ involves some term in $\log x$. As a simple (and well-known) example, lets take $f(x) = \frac{\log x}{x}$.

1. The standard method is to split the integral, $\int_1^x = \int_1^\infty - \int_x^\infty$, and approximate each part. This leads to the conclusion that
   $$\int_1^x(t-[t])f'(t)dt = K + O(f(x))$$ for some constant $K$ (equal to the first integral). However, what's wrong with doing the following?
   $$\int_1^x (t-[t])f'(t)dt \leq \int_1^x f'(t)dt = f(x)-f(1)$$
   If $f(1)\neq 0$, then this tells us that the integral is $O(1)$, so it's a less good approximation for the integral than if we'd split it up. However, when $f(x)=\frac{\log x}x$, we have $f(1)=0$, so the constant term has disappeared and thus we can conclude $$\int_1^x (t-[t])\left(\frac{\log t}t\right)'dt = O\left(\frac{\log x}x\right).$$ Since there is now no constant $K$, there must be something wrong in this argument, but what?
2. When $f(x)$ involves a logarithm, it's typically stated in the question that the approximation is valid for $x\geq 2$. Obviously if $x<2$ then $\sum_{n\leq x}f(x)=0$, but where does this condition actually come into play in the solution?

Comment: You need $\lvert f'(t)\rvert$ in the estimate. And if $f$ is not monotonic, that gets you a constant again.

Comment: Yes, quite right, thanks. So for $f(x)=\log x/x$, we have $\leq \int_1^x|f'(t)|dt = \int_1^e f'(t)dt - \int_e^x f'(t)dt$ whence we get $2f(e)-f(x)$ which is $O(1)$. That requires $x\geq e$, though, which is more stringent than $x\geq 2$...